# How to associate the same operation to a set of buttons programmatically in tkinter?

Tags: python, list, button, tkinter, configure

I have been working on a Python/Tkinter project that requires programatically created buttons from a list as below.

When a certain button is pressed, I would like that button to become `"sunken"` until another button is pressed, at that stage that button would become `"sunken"`, and the button first clicked would become `'normal'`.

So far I can't figure out how to do this without having to code each button individually.

Ideally the `relief` would be set in the `press()` function.

```
import tkinter


window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Practice UI")
window.grid()

numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]

def buttonCreator(labels):
    n = 0
    button = []
    for x in range(0,3):
        for y in range(0,3):
            if n<=len(labels)-1:
                button.append(tkinter.Button(window, text = labels[n], command = lambda x = labels[n]:press(x)))
                button[n].grid(row = x, column = y)
            n +=1

def press(value):
    print(value)

buttonCreator(numbers)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What are you having problems with? It looks like you're able to create the buttons, and to associate a command with each button. What is it that you don't know how to do? Are you aware of the `config` method on button widgets?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  Upon being pressed, I would like the button pressed to become 'sunken'.  I would then like the button to  return to the default state 'normal' once the next button has been pressed.  I can't figure out how to use the config method later on as the individual buttons don't have labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply return `button` and use it to access your buttons in `press()`:

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.grid()

# changed to integers so we can loop through the
# values in press() and use them as indices
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def buttonCreator(labels):
    n = 0
    button = []
    for x in range(0, 3):
        for y in range(0, 3):
            if n <= len(labels) - 1:
                button.append(tkinter.Button(window, text=labels[n],
                                             command=lambda x=labels[n]:press(x)))
                button[n].grid(row=x, column=y)
            n += 1
    return button # added a return statement

def press(value):
    for x in numbers:
        # index is x-1 because 1 is in button[0], etc
        button[x-1]['relief'] = 'sunken' if x == value else 'raised'

button = buttonCreator(numbers)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the behavior of a group of radiobuttons so you should use those.

Conveniently radiobuttons have an attribute `indicatoron` which

> Normally a radiobutton displays its indicator. If you set this option to zero, the indicator disappears, and the entire widget becomes a “push-push” button that looks raised when it is cleared and sunken when it is set. You may want to increase the borderwidth value to make it easier to see the state of such a control.

thus, when set to zero it does **precisely** what you request.

Answer (score 0):

Just for an example, I'll create two buttons with the reaction you wanted:

```
from Tkinter import *

win = Tk()

def press1():
    button1["relief"] = "sunken"
    button2["relief"] = "normal"
def press2():
    button1["relief"] = "normal"
    button2["relief"] = "sunken"

button1 = Button(win, text="Button 1", command=press1)
button2 = Button(win, text="Button 2", command=press2)

button1.pack()
button2.pack()

button1.grid(row=1, column=1)
button2.grid(row=1, column=2)

win.mainloop()
```

Should work. A second way:

```
from Tkinter import *

win = Tk()

def press(buttonnumber):
    if buttonnumber==1:
        button1["relief"] = "sunken"
        button2["relief"] = "normal"
    elif buttonnumber==2:
        button1["relief"] = "normal"
        button2["relief"] = "sunken"
    else: 
        raise Exception("No Button Number \"%d\"" % buttonnumber)

button1 = Button(win, text="Button 1", command=lambda: press(1))
button2 = Button(win, text="Button 2", command=lambda: press(2))

button1.pack()
button2.pack()

button1.grid(row=1, column=1)
button2.grid(row=1, column=2)

win.mainloop()
```