# How to change a Button's options in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *


bgColour="lightblue"

def changeColour():
    bgColour="lightgreen"

def settings():
    global window1

    window1=Tk()
    window1.minsize(width=400, height=600)
    window1.maxsize(width=400, height=600)
    window1.title("Boja pozadine")
    bg_colour1 = Frame(window1, bg=bgColour, width=400, height=600)
    bg_colour1.pack()

    naslov_bojaPozadine = Label(window1,
                                text="Background color",
                                bg=bgColour,
                                font=("Arial", 15, "bold"))
    naslov_bojaPozadine.place(x=20,y=10)

    light_blue = Button(window1, text="Light blue", bg=bgColour, bd=3)
    light_blue.place(x=20,y=50, width=100)
    light_green = Button(window1,text="light green", command=changeColour)
    light_green.place(x=20,y=80, width=100)

settings()
window1.mainloop()
```

How to replace all `bg` colour with button?
**Can you help please** *I am making app.*
Why I need to add more details if I have too much details?
What is going on with this?

Comment: ***Why*** more details? Because it helps others figure-out what you are asking. Plus gives them something to use to reproduce the problem and possibly provide you an answer/solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to associate the same operation to a set of buttons programmatically in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497374/how-to-associate-the-same-operation-to-a-set-of-buttons-programmatically-in-tkin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not completely sure I understand your question, but perhaps this following will help. I added a parameter to the `changeColour()` function that tells is what widget to change and modified the `command` keyword argument passed to it so that one will be passed to when it's called. Also did something similar to the `command` to the other button that changes the color back to the default.

```
bgColour = "lightblue"  # Default background colour.

def changeColour(widget, colour):
    widget.configure(bg=colour)

def settings():
    global window1

    window1=Tk()
    window1.minsize(width=400, height=600)
    window1.maxsize(width=400, height=600)
    window1.title("Boja pozadine")
    bg_colour1 = Frame(window1, bg=bgColour, width=400, height=600)
    bg_colour1.pack()

    naslov_bojaPozadine = Label(window1,
                                text="Background color",
                                bg=bgColour,
                                font=("Arial", 15, "bold"))
    naslov_bojaPozadine.place(x=20,y=10)

    light_blue = Button(window1, text="Light blue", bg=bgColour, bd=3,
                        command=lambda: changeColour(bg_colour1, bgColour))
    light_blue.place(x=20,y=50, width=100)
    light_green = Button(window1,text="light green",
                         command=lambda: changeColour(bg_colour1, "light green"))
    light_green.place(x=20,y=80, width=100)

settings()
window1.mainloop()
```